# ST_INTERSECTS use Jts Polygon and Querydsl

Tags: java, querydsl, jts

I need to check if the coordinates are in the polygon using QueryDSL.
I have jts package for Geometry type.
My class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "polygon")
public class PolygonEntity {

    @Id
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "geometry", nullable = false)
    private Geometry geometry;
}
```

For example, I used native query with JPA:

```
Query(
            value = "SELECT * from polygon " +
                    "where ST_INTERSECTS(ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(?1, ?2), 4326), polygon.geometry)",
            nativeQuery = true
    )
    Collection<PolygonEntity> findByCoordinate(@NonNull Double lon, @NonNull Double lat);
```

Now I need to get a Predicate for my jpa repository using QueryDSL, but I do not know how

I try:

```
JTSGeometryExpression jtsGeometryExpression = JTSGeometryExpressions.asJTSGeometry(polygonLinkEntity.polygon.geometry);
BooleanExpression expression = jtsGeometryExpression.intersects(filter.getCoordinate());
```

but i got exception:
unknown operation with operator INTERSECTS and args [polygonLinkEntity.polygon.geometry, POINT (34.317027 53.379137)]

Answer (score 0):

I used **querydsl-spatial** and call polygonLinkEntity.polygon.geometry.intersects(coordinate)